# Changing the PS1 on an interactive bash subshell easily

Tags: bash

I have a situation where I need to provide a subshell to a user mid-way through a longish process. I would like to change the prompt to remind the user that they are in a special subshell and haven't gone through the rest of the process yet. I thought that this would do what I want...

```
echo "PS1='foo:'" | bash -i
```

But when I enter that line, this is the output I get

```
me@mercury:~$ PS1='foo:'
foo:exit
me@mercury:~$
```

Is there a simple way around this? I could writeup my own custom bashrc... but I'd prefer to preserve the user's usual bash-shell setup.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use process substitution to essentially make a ~/.bashrc that only exists for the `bash -i` invocation like so:

```
 bash --rcfile <(echo "PS1='foo: '") -i
```

Answer (score 11):

If you still want the `~/.bashrc` to be read and assuming the `~/.bashrc` does not set `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, you could use this trick:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="foo: ";unset PROMPT_COMMAND' bash
```

Another approach which would work even if your rc files set `$PS1` and `$PROMPT_COMMAND` would be to do (from a zsh/bash/ksh93 shell) something like this:

```
(
  export IN_FD
  exec {IN_FD}<&0
  echo 'PS1="foo: "; exec <&"$IN_FD" {IN_FD}<&-' | bash -i
)
```

That is feed the `PS1="foo: "` via a pipe and then tell `bash` to switch stdin to the original stdin.

That has the side effect of displaying a prompt and that command line on stderr. You could work around it with:

```
(
  export IN_FD ERR_FD
  exec {IN_FD}<&0 {ERR_FD}>&2 2> /dev/null
  echo 'PS1="foo: "; exec <&"$IN_FD" {IN_FD}<&- 2>&"$ERR_FD" {ERR_FD}>&-' |
    bash -i
)
```

Though that has the side effect of hiding the error messages output by your startup files if any.

Comment: I must assume that PROMPT_COMMAND is set.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best answer since you don't mess up with the subshell environment.

Comment: Great answer. This works for commands that run subshell on their own. It helped me updating promp in [aws-vault](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault).

Answer (score 10):

I think it would be better to use `env PS1="foo: " /bin/bash --norc -i` instead of using the `--rcfile` option.  The environment is preserved, not overwritten by the dot files and the PS1 environment variable is set before entering the shell.

You might also want to think about opening a restricted shell, if the calling program gives extra privs. `env PS1="foo: " PATH=$RESTRICTED_PATH /bin/rbash --norc -i` for whatever value you want for $RESTRICTED_PATH.

Or have an already prefabricated bashrc file:

```
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    source /etc/bashrc
fi
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
PS1="foo:"
PATH=$RESTRICTED_PATH
```

And then call with `/bin/bash -rcfile ~/.bashrc.appsubshell -i`

Comment: The usecase is pretty simple... the utility does a fairly complex transformation on a vendor's code repo, importing it to a local mercurial repo. Prints a bunch of status details out (like how many roots/heads/branches the resulting repo has), and then launches a shell to let the user investigate further. When they finish, the script asks if it should continue with the "difficult to undo" parts of the process. (In summary... privs aren't an issue here, but I want to make the users as comfortable with their own settings as possible)

Comment: In my case I was invoking a bash shell from inside a Ruby Rake task with the `sh` command, so this was the best solution by far.

Comment: With `--rcfile` you can do something like `<(cat ~/.bashrc; echo 'PS1=foo')`, whereas using --norc, you don't capture functions defined in bashrc (env vars should be in bash_profile, not bashrc). functions aren't in the environment, they need to be redefined in subshells. Of course `--rc <(...)` is just an inline version of the prefabricated rc.

Comment: The most practical effect of not sourcing ~/.bashrc is not including completion.

Answer (score 3):

After reading this page, here's how I ended up doing it.

In `.bashrc`:

```
# use prompt postfix
if [[ -n "$PROMPT_POSTFIX" ]]; then
    PS1="${PS1}${PROMPT_POSTFIX}"
fi
```

Then, in the script I'm running the interactive shell from:

`env PROMPT_POSTFIX="(whatever) " bash -i`

The problem with using `--norc` is that it doesn't pull in your `.bashrc` file, so your interactive subshell won't have things you're used to using in Bash, like your history commands, etc.  This way you can set `PROMPT_POSTFIX` whenever you call Bash and it will get added on to the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with SiegeX (who beat me to it :))

To explain the behaviour:

Bash will only start in interactive mode if its std in and out are normal terminals. That's not the case when piping in that initial command.

You can use the `-c` option to provide commands, but that also precludes interactive mode.

If you really want to preserve user rc, simply add some test/source statements in the rcfile string to source `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/bashrc` if the files exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'm launching a subshell from a script so I can't just preserve the current environment, but I want the user to have their environment setup anyway.

I don't want to require stuff in the user's bashrc which I cannot control.

So what I did is source their bashrc, throw out `PROMPT_COMMAND` if it exists, and then set the `PS1`.

```
bash --rcfile <(echo ". ~/.bashrc; unset PROMPT_COMMAND; PS1='foo shell > '") -i
```