# How change prompt of subshell

Tags: bash, zsh, prompt

I'm trying to create a simple script that, among other things, will create a subshell:

```
#!/bin/sh

# setup

"${@:-$SHELL}"

# teardown
```

The question is: I need to change the default prompt, so for example:

> $ # default shell
>   $ ./myscript
>   (myscript) $  # subshell
>   (myscript) $ exit
>   $

I tried to change `PROMPT` and `PS1`, but none of these works. How can I do that?

PS.: I need a solution that works both on Bash and ZSH, if possible.

Comment: Possible dublicate of [Changing the PS1 on an interactive bash subshell easily](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6796/changing-the-ps1-on-an-interactive-bash-subshell-easily)

Comment: Not exact duplicate as that other question was for `bash` only.

Comment: Does look like the right duplicate ;-(

Answer (score 7):

I think you can create a subshell with a different prompt like this:

```
$ bash --rcfile <(echo "PS1='subshell prompt: '") -i
```

#### Example

*Current env:*

```
$ bash --rcfile <(echo "PS1='subshell prompt$ '") -i
```

*In sub shell:*

```
subshell prompt$ echo hi
hi
subshell prompt$ exit
exit
```

*Back to original shell:*

```
$
```

Comment: You can use a `here string` instead of the process substitution. eg `<<< "PS1..."`.

Comment: @jordanm - can you provide an example? I messed around with this but couldn't get a working example using the here strings.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work might be because when you load the shell (which should be eg.: `/bin/bash`), it will end up reloading its configuration files, which include the environment variables for the prompt (eg.: `$HOME/.bashrc`) *after* being passed the environment variables you want - thus your variables are discarded.

You might want to check the options of the shell to load custom configuration files (eg.: `--rcfile` in Bash IINM) and use those as well as `\env` to pass the environment variables that you want. The problem is that once you do that firing the subshell becomes shell-dependant.

(**CAVEAT EMPTOR**: I do not consider this to be an answer yet - in particular, I have not tried any of this in my system yet.)